Nextjs 15 and Payloadcms config file
I've currently used next.config.js with withBundleAnalyzer:
import withPlugins from "next-compose-plugins";

const plugins = [
  withBundleAnalyzer({
    enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
  }),
];

export default withPlugins(plugins, {
  // next config here
}

I installed payloadcms 3 and the new next.config.js should be like this:
import { withPayload } from '@payloadcms/next/withPayload'

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  // Your Next.js config here
  experimental: {
    reactCompiler: false
  }
}

// Make sure you wrap your `nextConfig`
// with the `withPayload` plugin

export default withPayload(nextConfig) 

The question: How can I implement BundlyAnalyzer with payloadcms 3?
